# How to force selenium webdriver not to open "SaveAs" dialog while loading the page using Axe-Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, puppeteer

If I'm using the same sample code [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@axe-core/puppeteer) to

if I'm navigating to a link that opens SaveAs dialog (something like [this](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/thank-you/sdk-3.1.402-windows-x64-installer))

How can I force the web driver not to open the dialog using launch options, for example if I wanna disable sand-box, I'll add it in the args like

```
browser = await puppeteer.launch({
          args: ['--no-sandbox'],            
          })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925222/how-to-force-chrome-to-not-open-saveas-dialog-when-downloading-a-url

Comment: Nope, I'm trying to use launch option, I'm not downloading anything, the link I'm navigating to is a download link, but I don't want the save dialog to open